# How does Scrapy save crawl state?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am able to save my crawl state and Scrapy successfully continues from where I cut it off. I have kept the start_urls constant each time I restart the spider i.e. the order and the list of start_urls fed each time that the spider is restarted is constant. But I need to do a random shuffle of my start_urls as I have URLs from different domains and well as in from same domain but as they are in order, the crawl delay is significantly slowing down my crawl speed. My list is 10s of millions and I have already crawled a million URLs. So I wouldn't want to jeopardize anything or restart the crawl.

I have seen that requests.seen holds what looks like hashed values of the URLs that have been visited. And from Scrapy code I am certain that it's used to filter duplicates. But I am not sure what either spider.state or requests.queue does to help with saving state or restarting the crawl.

Comment: I am trying to find the same thing, requests.seen alone is ignoring redundant crawls in my case, can you please post an answer, if you found a solution for it

Answer (score -1):

You can write these requests to a txt file while seperating them when request is called by **callback** or **errback**.

```py
def start_requests(self):
    for u in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(u, callback=self.parse,
                                    errback=self.err,
                                    dont_filter=True)

def parse(self, response):
    with open('successful_requests.txt', 'a') as out:
        out.write(response.url + '\n')

def err(self, failure):
    with open('failed_requests.txt', 'a') as out:
        out.write(response.url + ' ' + str(failure) + '\n')
```

To reach statea of requests, just read these txt files.